How to show the text and the icon on the image. jetpack compose
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(0.35f),

        ) {
            IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp).background(Color.White),
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = null)

            }
                Text("Hello", style = TextStyle(Color.White, fontSize = 10.sp))
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.white)
                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(null),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        modifier = Modifier // Adjust the size of the image as needed
                        .fillMaxSize()
            )

        }

I am expecting to see text on the image and also the icon. if those two can be visible they are currently not visible

Try putting the image first, then the icon and text. At the moment, the image is hiding the icon and text.

You didn't specify any positioning information for your composables so they are all placed at the top-right corner of their parent. They will be drawn in the order they appear: First the IconButton is drawn, then, on top of it Text, and then everthing is hidden under the Image that you set to fill the entire available space. As a result, only the Image can be seen.
I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but if you move the Image to the top then all three composables are visible. If you would want them to not be drawn over another, you should change the Box to a Column or something similar: Column lays out its children so they don't overlap, spreading them vertically.

Put your image before your Text and Icon:
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(0.35f),

        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.white)
                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(null),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        modifier = Modifier // Adjust the size of the image as needed
                        .fillMaxSize()
            )

            IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp).background(Color.White),
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = null)

            }
            Text("Hello", style = TextStyle(Color.White, fontSize = 10.sp))

        }

Adjust your modifier to locate it in the right position.
Hope that what you need.

In the provided code, the Image is drawn above the Icon. So it is hiding the Icon.  It is because of the order in which these are called.
You can update the code as
    Box{
//        Image
//        Icon
//        Text
    }

one can use the Column or Row to align the Icon and Text.
